# Export flow types from a package which is using flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am using a package (I am the author of it as well) in a project with flow set up.

The package is: https://github.com/OrigenStudio/material-ui-layout

Using it as:

```js
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import Layout, { BasicAppBar } from 'material-ui-layout';

//...
```

The Flow error is:

`Flow error: [Flow] Cannot resolve module 'material-ui-layout'. [InferError]`

I have checked this documentation: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/

However, I am not sure how to implement it. Are there any references or similar packages that use flow?

Comment: A common way to export types is to use flow-copy-source

Comment: The error indicates that Flow isn't finding your module. The importing environment is the problem. Btw, that "Layout, { BasicAppBar }" creeps me out. Why mix a default export with non-default exports?

Comment: The short answer is that this isn't currently very easy to do. As @FezVrasta notes, flow-copy-source is one potential solution, and that usually works pretty well. I'm currently working on a better way to do this (basically, you should be able to autogenerate libdefs such as those in flow-typed automatically, and I'm working on making that happen).